# How to detect last NSColorWell color selected in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit, nscolorwell

Is there any way to detect last NSColorWell color selected?

So far i have create NSColorWell with action and target programmatically, So how many time i changed the color that method is called  that much time. So i want to identified last selected color of NSColorWell.

Comment: So what you're actually asking for is the **current selection**, right?

Answer (score 0):

**NSColorPanelResponderMethod** category (informal protocol) on **NSObject** implements a method called **changeColor:**. So, you could override this method inside your class to detect the color changes for **NSColorWell**.

```
@interface MyClass:NSObject 
 @property(nonatomic, strong) NSColor *lastColor;
@end

@implementation MyClass
  - (void)colorChanged:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Last color %@", lastColor);
    NSColor *newColor = [sender color];
    NSLog(@"NSColorWell changed color %@", [sender color]);
  }
@end
```

If you want to be able to keep track of the last font, then you would create a property and everytime the font changes, assign the new font to the property. This way you will be able to keep track of the last font.

Comment: I want to detect only the last color? When i release the mouse on color well??

Comment: So, the colorChanged: method is triggered everytime you change the color, you could then store the value in some property to know the last change.